# React Hooks - Local Weather API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making an app to get the local weather using React Hooks and Axios.

I am using geo location and the free code camp weather API.

I have created a component called Weather.js, sometimes it receives the data but sometimes it doesn't come through any idea what is wrong with this?

You can see I'm trying to log the data to the console.

I've tried doing things like

if(props) {
etc....
}

to check if the data is there but I keep getting loads of errors.

Here is the link to my codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/weather-app-xrxdu?file=/src/Components/Weather.js

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render a `object` in react. You can render it as a string for now to test:

```
Weather.js

return JSON.stringify({props});
```

Comment: ah ok, thanks! I'll try that! I thought I had fixed it but then it broke again 

Answer (score 0):

First Pass the dependency to useEffect empty array [] to [location.coordinates] so, that usEffect trigger wehen location coordinates changes and fetch new data.

And in weather.js

```
import React from "react";

const Weather = (props) => {


  return 
  <>
  <p>{JSON.stringify({props})}</p>
  
  </>

}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you mean in useGeoLocation.js ?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
      onError({
        code: 0,
        message: "Geolocation not supported"
      });
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
  }, [location.coordinates]);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys() and then map it to use it's values in component rendering.

```
const Weather = (props) => {
  
  {console.log(JSON.stringify(props.data))}

  return (
    <div >
      <h1>Weather Component</h1>
      {!!props.data && Object.keys(props.data).map((i) => (
        <p> {i} </p>))}

    </div>
  );

  
};

export default Weather;
```

Comment: Oh ok, why do you use Object.keys()  ?

Comment: Thanks for your help !